Entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value is already being tracked when adding new object
The relevant models look like this:
Quiz:
public class Quiz
{
    // Primary key
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public QuizTypes QuizType { get; set; }
    
    public int TimeLimit { get; set; }
    public bool AverageTimeForQuestions { get; set; }
    
    // One-to-many relationship
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

QuizLog:
public class QuizLog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public QuizTypes QuizType { get; set; }
    
    public int TimeLimit { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionLog>? Questions { get; set; } = new List<QuestionLog>();
}

User:
[Table("Us3r_Data")]
public partial class User
{
    public User() { }

    public User(string username, string password, Role role, IConfiguration config)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password + config["Password:Seed"]);
        this.Role = role;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public bool FinalTest { get; set; }
    
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public QuizTypes QuizType { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<UserLogs>? UserLog { get; set; }
}

UserLogs:
public class UserLogs
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; } = null!;
    public QuizLog QuizSnapshot { get; set; }
    public Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }
}

QuizType:
public class QuizTypes
{
    public Guid Id [ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

The endpoint looks like this, with the line causing the error highlighted:
  [HttpPut("quizAnswer/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> QuizAnswer(Guid id, [FromBody] QuizLog quiz)
        {
            try
            {

                var localDb = _db;
                Guid userId = JwtAuthorization.GetUserId(Request.Headers.Authorization!, _conf);

                /*var user = await _db.Users.Include(j => j.UserLog).AsNoTracking().Include(qt => qt.QuizType).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == userId);*/
                var user = await localDb.Users.FindAsync(userId);
                /*var dbQuiz = await _db.Quiz.AsNoTracking().Include(qt => qt.QuizType).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);*/
                var dbQuiz = await localDb.Quiz.FindAsync(id);
                var tempQuiz = quiz;

                if (user == null || dbQuiz == null)
                {
                    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("no user or quiz found");
                    return NotFound();
                }
                if (!user.FinalTest)
                {
                    return Ok();
                }

                tempQuiz.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                foreach (var item in tempQuiz.Questions!)
                {
                    item.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    foreach (var answer in item.Answers!)
                    {
                        answer.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    }
                }



                UserLogs log = new UserLogs();
                log.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                log.QuizSnapshot = tempQuiz;
                log.Quiz = dbQuiz;
                log.User = user;
                log.SubmitDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                user.FinalTest = false;



                await _db.UserLogs.AddAsync(log);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("\n" + ex.ToString() + "\n");
                return BadRequest("something went wrong");
            }
        }


My DbContext:
public class QuizDatabase : DbContext
{
    public QuizDatabase(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Quiz>().HasMany(i => i.Questions).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Question>().HasMany(i => i.Answers).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(i => i.UserLog).WithOne(j => j.User).HasForeignKey(l => l.UserId).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuizLog>().HasMany(i => i.Questions).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionLog>().HasMany(i => i.Answers).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Quiz>().HasOne(i => i.QuizType).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<QuizLog>().HasOne(i => i.QuizType).WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOne(q => q.QuizType).WithMany();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLogs> UserLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Quiz> Quiz { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuizTypes> QuizTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AnswerLog> AnswerLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuestionLog> QuestionLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuizLog> QuizLogs { get; set; }
}

The full exception looks something like this:
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'QuizTypes' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: [guid]aaa}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at SOP_QUIZ.Controllers.QuizController.QuizAnswer(Guid id, QuizLog quiz) in [...] /Controllers/QuizController.cs:line 308

There are 3 QuizTypes in total for the UserLog:

Quiz -> aaa
QuizSnapshot -> aaa
User -> bbb (different)

What I've Tried

AsNoTracking():
I tried using .AsNoTracking() on the entities I'm fetching from the database with these lines:
var user = await _db.Users.Include(j => j.UserLog).Include(qt => qt.QuizType).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == userId);
var dbQuiz = await _db.Quiz.Include(qt => qt.QuizType).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

I assumed this would remove the tracking, but I realized that calling Add() at the end begins tracking again, which led to the same issue.

Foreign Key Annotations:
I tried using foreign key annotations in User, Quiz, and QuizLog, adding a new property like public Guid QuizTypeId { get; set; }, but this didn't solve the problem.

Attaching Existing Entities:
I tried attaching the existing QuizTypes entities before saving, hoping this would ensure that only one instance was being used across all three objects, but this also didn't help.

Clearing the Change Tracker:
I called _db.ChangeTracker.Clear() right before calling _db.UserLogs.Add(log);, and I verified that no entities were being tracked before the clear. However, this also didn't resolve the issue.


Any help is appreciated.

It seems like you're making life much harder that it's supposed to be.. With EF, you retrieve an object from the DB, you modify its properties and you call save on the context. None of this messing around with Entity, and detaching/attaching, fiddling with the object state etc. You can use FindAsync instead of this "look locally then retrieve from db if it is not local", by the way

Don't keep contexts for a long time, don't serialize db entities to a UI and then (when you get them back modified by the user) try to re reste DB entities and attach them to the change tracker and convince EF it's an object it should use to do something with the DB.. Have different model classes for your UI, ask EF to search the DB, copy data from the UI object to the DB object you get from EF (maybe using an auto mapper) and save.. The more you try to micromanage EF the harder your life becomes

The code i submitted was the latest attempt, but i did ofcourse start out with the simplest slate, with just the database calls, making sure they arent null and then adding a new object.
i have gone back to that, replaced the database calls with the findAsync, but it throws "Duplicate Entry 'GUID' for key 'PRIMARY'. let me update my code on my post to reflect my changes.

If var p = await context.People.FindAsync(123); p.Name = "John Smith"; await context.SaveChangesAsync(); throws a duplicate PK exception, your problems are elsewhere

Do not use AsNoTracking() if you update enitites.

Add foreign-key properties QuizTypeId besides QuizType and set those instead of QuizType.

Passing around detached entity graphs like this is going to see this problem fairly often. Any and all references to existing data must be vetted against the tracking cache prior to attaching or inserting a row. In your case it is highlighting the QuizType seeing as QuizType is being referenced by pretty much every other entity being used here. I'd avoid reassigning references as it makes the code more confusing to read, also naming is important so if you get a QuizLog, call it quizLog, not quiz when there is a Quiz entity.
public async Task<IActionResult> QuizAnswer(Guid id, [FromBody] QuizLog quizLog)
{
    try
    {
        Guid userId = JwtAuthorization.GetUserId(Request.Headers.Authorization!, _conf);

        var user = await _db.Users
             .Include(u => u.UserLog)
             .Include(u => u.QuizType)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
        var quiz = await _db.Quiz
             .Include(q => q.QuizType)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);

        if (user == null || quiz == null)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("no user or quiz found");
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (!user.FinalTest)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        // This is what you need to do for any and all references in a
        // detached entity. Check the .Local tracking cache for an 
        // existing tracked reference. If found, replace the reference
        // with the tracked one. If not found, Attach.
        var existingQuizType = _db.QuizTypes.Local
           .FirstOrDefault(qt = qt.Id == quizLog.QuizType.Id);
        if (existingQuizType != null)
           quizLog.QuizType = existingQuizType;
        else
           _db.Attach(quizLog.QuizType);

        quizLog.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // Consider using Identity columns with new IDs set in DB. Default GUID is terrible for PKs /w clustered indexes. None of this code should be necessary when set up correctly.
        foreach (var item in quizLog.Questions)
        {
            item.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // Identity
            foreach (var answer in item.Answers)
            {
                answer.Id = Guid.NewGuid(); // Identity
            }
        }

        UserLogs log = new UserLogs
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            QuizSnapshot = quizLog;
            Quiz = quiz;
            User = user;
            SubmitDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            FinalTest = false;
        };


        await _db.UserLogs.AddAsync(log);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("\n" + ex.ToString() + "\n");
        return BadRequest("something went wrong");
    }
}

There may be more changes needed, but I would look at implementing identity columns properly in the database schema to do away with all of that ID setting. GUID IDs are a poor choice for a typical clustered index on a PK, notably better would be a sequential GUID, much better would be a sequential numeric identity column. If you do use a GUID (sequential or default) then I recommend scheduling a regular index maintenance job on the database to regularly reorganize the index and reduce fragmentation.

Thank you for the answer, it was indeed what i needed and was missing. I will look into the GUID / Identity changes you proposed, but so far it is working flawlessly. Thank you for the answer and insight.
